# Gdb wont put a break at a nop

Tags: assembly, gdb, breakpoints

I made a simple assembly program just for the sake of learning and tried putting a break at a no operation but assembly won't listen and i rarely happen to be able to put breaks in code overall.

Would you explain me where i can put breaks and why i can't put it at the no operation address?

```
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
0x00000000004000b0 <+0>:    nop
0x00000000004000b1 <+1>:    mov    $0x4,%eax
0x00000000004000b6 <+6>:    mov    $0x1,%ebx
0x00000000004000bb <+11>:   mov    $0x600124,%ecx
0x00000000004000c0 <+16>:   mov    $0xd,%edx
0x00000000004000c5 <+21>:   int    $0x80
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break 0x4000b0
Function "0x4000b0" not defined.
```

Comment: You should be able to `b _start` because you have a label there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

break *0x4000b0

add a star symbol before the address